# What is PDF content stream and in what cases do we need to update this stream...?

Tags: itext, itext7

I'm new to iText. I'm using iText 7.

1. In iText 5 there were two content streams Under content and over content. What is the alternative in iText 7,  If someone wants to add content in under or over content stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please create a `PdfCanvas` using `PdfPage#newContentStreamBefore()` or `PdfPage#newContentStreamAfter()`

For example, in the following snippet I will create a `PdfCanvas` instance for some already existed `PdfPage` instance (page)

```
PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page.newContentStreamBefore(), page.getResources(), pdfDoc);
```

Then you can use this `PdfCanvas` instance as a usual one: the inly difference is that the content will be rendered before the other content (e.g. over)